Looking for a letter from H. P. Lovecraft to R. E. Howard
I'm looking for a letter from H.P. Lovecraft to Robert E. Howard. This letter was sent on 12 Sept 1931 and is referred to as MF1.210 in the book A Means to Freedom: The Letters of H.P. Lovecraft and Robert E. Howard, edited by Joshi, Schultz and Burke in 2009 (Hippocampus Press). Unfortunately I have only found the text in French and I need it in the original version.
In this letter there is a passage more our less saying (translating from French):

I envy you for having seen the fall of a meteorite, or rather the fire and the resulting report. Visitors from outer space always fascinate me, and I always stop to think in the lobby of the American Museum in New York, where many giant specimens are arranged on pedestals. It's exciting for the imagination to get hold of a piece of material substance from the Outside.

Does anyone own this book and could send me the exact English text and the page numbering?

Obligatory XKCD reference: if somebody saw it fall, it wasn't a meteorite :-) https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1723:_Meteorite_Identification

MF.210 is referenced here on Reddit, in the original English.

I envy you your sight of a meteorite's fall—or rather, the blaze and
report incidental thereto. Visitors from outer space always fascinate
me, and I always pause reflectively in the hall of the American Museum
in N.Y., where many giant specimens are ranged about on pedestals. It
is enthralling to the imagination to lay actual hands on a piece of
material substance from Outside.
H. P. Lovecraft to Robert E. Howard, 12 Sep 1931, MF1.210

It was drawn in response to a letter from Howard.

I remember, very faintly, the fall of a meteorite in South Texas, many years ago. I was about four years old at the time, and was at the house of an uncle, in a little town about forty miles from the Mexican Border; a town which had recently sprung up like a mushroom from the wilderness and was still pretty tough. I remember waking suddenly and sitting up in bed, seeing everything bathed in a weird blue light, and hearing a terrific detonation. My uncle — an Indian — had enemies of desperate character, and in the excitement it was thought they had dynamited the house. There was a general leaping up and snatching of guns, but nothing further occurred. Next day it was learned that a meteorite had fallen. People who saw it described it as being about the size and shape of a barrel, and averred it burst twice before striking the ground, making a loud explosion and shedding that strange blue light over everything. No trace of it was ever found.
Robert E. Howard to H. P. Lovecraft, Aug 1931


Thanks a lot ! I need also the page number of the book (it's for a university work), so I let the question open... I will ask also on Reddit, but as the exchange took place 6 years ago, I'm a bit afraid ;-)

@Fabrice - Your university library will almost certainly have a hard copy of A Means to Freedom, or at the least can order it.
